# Creating an overlay in Xamarin Forms TabbedPages

Tags: forms, xamarin, overlay, tabbedpage

I'm working on a Radio App, using a TabbedPage layout.
Basically, I have 3 bottom tabs, and I want them all to show a simple radio player (which shows the current song / radio program being played, and the play / pause button).

I've set up the player inside a ContentView, and can achieve this result by placing the PlayerView on each tab, thus, having 3 copies of the same view, one on each tab.

Is there a simple way to overlay the player view over the TabbedPage?

Comment: are you using the tabs to simulate radio buttons?  I would try something like a segmented control instead.

Comment: No. I have 3 tabs, and a Player View, which is called upon each tab, via a AbsoluteLayout position.
https://imgur.com/qv1aymj mock of the App.

Comment: You can refer to the float action buttonhttps://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/93644/floating-action-button-at-the-bottom-of-the-xaml-page

Comment: Man, I am trying to do the same thing and have given-up after 3 months of dead-ends. I have a custom renderer for tab pages but can't get the overlay do play nice with its datacontext